Azure Synapse CI/CD Pipeline - Override Apache Spark Pool Name in Notebooks
I'm working on setting up a CI/CD pipeline for an Azure Synapse workspace, and I need to create custom parameters in the deployment process to handle environment-specific values. Specifically, I need to override the Apache Spark pool name used in the development environment (synDEVSPark) to the production Apache Spark pool name (synPROSPark1).
I've followed the instructions from the Microsoft documentation, but I'm encountering an error during the synapse deployment task.
Here are the steps I've taken:

Created a template-parameters-definition.json file to define the parameters (shown in the image below).
Set up the override parameter in the Synapse deployment task (shown in the image below).
Created a pipeline variable to hold the production Apache Spark pool name (shown in the below image).

Despite these efforts, the deployment fails with the following error (shown in the image below):
Failed to fetch the deployment status {"code":"400","message":"CreateOrUpdateNotebook failed: [statusCode from ADF:BadRequest, ErrorMessage:{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference 'synDEVSPark'...

I also read a blog post, used in a comment to a somewhat similar question, which mentioned using information within a JSON file that defines the linked service to create the parameter override. However, synDEVSPark is not a linked service but an Apache Spark pool under Analytics pools, so it seems that the blog post cannot help me in this case.
How can I correctly override the Apache Spark pool name in the Synapse deployment task to ensure it uses the production Spark pool (synPROSPark1) instead of the development Spark pool (synDEVSPark)? Is there a specific way to reference the Apache Spark pool in the parameters, considering it is not a linked service?
Any help or guidance on what I might be doing wrong or how to properly configure the override parameters would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Maybe you can try to replace the spark pool with new one in all places manually, like TemplateForWorkspace.json and notebook.json, check if it works firstly. After it works, you can check the minimum change required, could consider to use Replace Tokens to replace the spark pool name, before the deployment in CICD then.

sounds great, @wadezhou-MSFT , I will try and post the results, thanks

If you are just updating the JSON directly, be aware that there are other Object nodes that require updating as well. Specifically, the metadata.a365ComputeOptions.name and metadata.a365ComputeOptions.sparkVersion - it's a real shame that Synapse does not have a "Related" reference for Spark Pools, nor a way to update the references in place. It would be especially useful when they force retire older Spark versions as they are doing right now with 2.4.

@JoelCochran, thanks for your comment. It is reassuring to know that there is no way to update Spark Pool references in place in Synapse. I was going crazy! XD

@TsuKernik, you can check the link, which has guide to deploy with a new spark pool.

@wadezhou-MSFT, thanks so much! That blog post saved me!

Glad to know it helps :), you are welcome. I will post the blog link below so that it could help others who have same queries, thanks.

To override Apache Spark Pool Name in Notebooks, can follow the blog to update the template definition file (template-parameters-definition.json):
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/cicd-automation-in-synapse-analytics-taking-advantage-of-custom/ba-p/3513546
